# Extracting JSON Elements with JS

Tags: javascript, json

This is my JSON:

```
   "url": "http://www.myurl.com/",
    "language": "english",
    "concepts": [
        {
            "text": "world news",
            "relevance": "0.964403",
            "dbpedia": "http://dbpedia.org/resource/John_McCain",
            "freebase": "http://rdf.freebase.com/ns/guid.9202a8c04000641f800000000005767a"
```

I can retrieve the URL with this:

```
return object.url;
```

I would like to retrieve text:

```
return object.concepts[]
```

I feel like this is a simple solution but any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

```
return object.concepts;
```

will return the concepts array.

If you just want retrieve the text of the first element, you could do something like this:

```
return object.concepts[0].text;
```

Comment: Perfect. Thank you. If I wanted to select multiple "text" elements, would I use: return object.concepts[0, 1].text?

Comment: User, you can just try all this in the console. The answer is no.

Answer (score 0):

Try using jQuery.parseJSON
http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/

Comment: No need to as this is not a JSON string it's a JSON object.

Comment: @Interstellar_Coder - Thanks for correcting me. I though it as a json string.